# DocumentBrowserViewController "Select" button turns into a UIActivityIndicatorView after selecting multiple files

Tags: ios, swift

When I return to DocumentBrowserViewController after selecting multiple files the DocumentBrowserViewController "Select" button has turned into a UIActivityIndicatorView and is spinning merrily away. This does not happen if I select a single file.

This issue can be reproduced by creating an iOS Document Based App for an iPhone or iPad then...

1) In the DocumentBrowserViewController.swift file change the "allowsPickingMultipleItems = false" statement to "allowsPickingMultipleItems = true".

In the Info.plist change CFBundleDocumentTypes key from:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Images</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.plain-text</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string></string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

to:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Text</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>**public.image**</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array/>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string></string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

2) Build and run it.

3) Tap on the "Select" button and select two or more files.

4) Tapping on the "Open" button will take you to a simple UIView that displays the name of the first file selected and a "Done" button.

5) Tap on the "Done" button and you are back at the DocumentBrowserViewController view and you will notice that the button, formerly known as "Select", is now a spinning indicator.

Comment: please edit your question and post your code. Please take a look at how to provide a [mcve]